# SQL same column data

Tags: sql

I have a table
like

```
     Server           Instance
MURDW02D    WinA3_NetInstances
MURDW02D    WinA3_MemVirt
MURAW06D    WinA3_CPU
MURDW02D    WinA3_NetInst
MURDW02D    WinA3_CPUInst
MURAW06D    WinA3_Net
MURDW02D    WinA3_Mem
MURDW01D    WinA3_Mem
MURDW01D    WinA3_CPUInst
MURDW02D    WinA3_Net
MURDW02D    WinA3_CPUInst
MURAW07D    WinA3_Net
```

I would like to **SELECT MURDW01D and MURDW02D**
as they have **WinA3_Mem** and **WinA3_CPUInst** common.
There could be 3 fields which can be common.
Also, I want count of of the servers which have this in common
that is 2 in this case is it possible.

Query tried

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT HOSTNAME AS [Host], CLASS AS [class] FROM oncall) AS s PIVOT(COUNT(CLASS) FOR [CLASS] IN (WinA3_Proc)) AS pivot
```

This may be working not 100% sure , I have 50K records with 170 Instances and I am looking for Instances common on these servers.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM oncall
WHERE (CLASS LIKE '%WinA3%') AND (CLASS LIKE '%WinA3_CPUInst%')
```

Comment: Good Question. But first show what have tried so far? If you are new to SQL then show us what you have studied/referred?

Comment: I tried so many things to start with I tried  putting AND selecting Instance column , it gives me 0 count as both values are in same column so doesn't work.

Comment: I tried pivot then like SELECT     *
FROM         (SELECT     HOSTNAME AS [Host], CLASS AS [class]
                       FROM          oncall) AS s PIVOT(COUNT(CLASS) FOR [CLASS] IN (WinA3_Proc)) AS pivot

Comment: Please show your effort towards this problem.

Comment: Edit your post and write your Query.

Comment: SELECT     COUNT(*) AS Expr1
FROM         oncall
WHERE     (CLASS LIKE '%WinA3%') AND (CLASS LIKE '%WinA3_CPUInst%') This I think working to some extend not 100% sure

Comment: Thanks query added, I am a new user on this website so learning how to write good post :)

Comment: Thanks for Reply. Please add Output in your Post [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17738174/edit). So that it will be more clear, what actually nneded in O/P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @t as table (Servr varchar(max), INstance varchar(max))

insert into @t values ('MURDW02D',    'WinA3_NetInstances')
insert into @t values ('MURDW02D',    'WinA3_MemVirt')
insert into @t values ('MURAW06D',    'WinA3_CPU')
insert into @t values ('MURDW02D',    'WinA3_NetInst')
insert into @t values ('MURDW02D',    'WinA3_CPUInst')
insert into @t values ('MURAW06D',    'WinA3_Net')
insert into @t values ('MURDW02D',    'WinA3_Mem')
insert into @t values ('MURDW01D',   'WinA3_Mem')
insert into @t values ('MURDW01D',    'WinA3_CPUInst')
insert into @t values ('MURDW02D',    'WinA3_Net')
insert into @t values ('MURDW02D',    'WinA3_CPUInst')
insert into @t values ('MURAW07D',    'WinA3_Mem')

-- Get the servers and their counts which have both WinA3_Mem and WinA3_CPUInst
Select servr, count(*) serverCount from
(Select distinct servr, Instance from @t where instance LIKE 'WinA3_Mem%'
 union
Select distinct servr, Instance from @t where instance LIKE 'WinA3_CPUInst%') X
group by servr
having count(*) > 1
```

[Sample JSFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a6047/5)

Comment: How to put table on this website, some one corrected last time when I put

Comment: I tried But some how not worked, I tried on similar data
HOSTNAME CLASS
CDCAWV81 WinA3_LVola
CDCAWV81 WinA3_CPUTotal
CDCAWV80 WinA3_LVol
CDCAWV80 WinA3_CPUTotal

I tried this query and got zero result with like and = operator both
SELECT     HOSTNAME, COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM         oncall
WHERE     CLASS = 'WinA3_LVol' AND CLASS = 'WinA3_CPUTotal'
GROUP BY HOSTNAME

Comment: I can't vote require 15 reputation to vote also.. learning 1 question.. Do I new to put in HTML tags above table for discplay?

Comment: Your query gives count of each of these instances appeared in CLASS table But doesn't give me servername and count based on similar CLASS in two host names 


Got result like
 MURAW80U 13
 ATTANCTV04 7
 JDCWV007 6
 NCSAWDR01 13

Comment: Made changes to the query. I think it will work now.

Comment: Perfect in all means.. count is missing which I think I can do manually when I get the server name or I can do in excel

Comment: Just joinned Stackoverflow.. so can't vote

Comment: no problem, come back when you have enough reps :-)